# Display the data layer to info windows taken from GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, google-maps-api

I have a problem for displaying data to info windows on the Google Maps Data layer. Here I use GeoJSON to load data. can anyone help me?

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -2.9365327, lng: 104.4950964}
  });

  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    'https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.geojson');
  console.log( map.data);

 var ced = google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'click',function(event) {       
    console.log(event.feature.f)
    alert("Koordinat:lat: "+event.latLng.lat()+", lng: "+event.latLng.lng());
    alert(JSON.stringify(event.feature.f));
  });
}
```

At this moment I'm just can make data appear on alert method.

[image]

[image]

And I want to make the data show from info windows when that street was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You just have to use the *getProperty* method of the returned Feature object. See below:

```
var ced = google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'click',function(event) {       
   console.log(event.feature.getProperty('name'))
   alert("Koordinat:lat: "+event.latLng.lat()+", lng: "+event.latLng.lng());
   alert(event.feature.getProperty('name'));
});
```